# XML Data binding

Tags: xml, wpf, listbox

I have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<Month name="Jan">
  <Comment source="Controller">
    <refs>
      <ref account="1" content="1. Zeile"/>
      <ref account="2" content="2. Zeile"/>
      <ref account="3" content="3. Zeile"/>
    </refs>
  </Comment>
  <Comment source="NatCo">
    <refs>
       <ref account="1" content="4. Zeile"/>
       <ref account="2" content="5. Zeile"/>
       <ref account="3" content="6. Zeile"/>
    </refs>       
  </Comment>
</Month>
```

and two listboxes in my XAML. The first listbox should show the Comments from Comment source Controller. The second should show the Comments from the National Company. How can I specify the databinding in terms of the source attribute?

At the moment my databinding looks like this:

```
ListBox Name="lstNaCo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Element[Comment].Element[refs].Elements[ref]}"
```

Is it possible to hand over an additional parameter for comments element? For example in this way

```
Path=Element[Comment@source='Controller'].Element[refs].Elements[ref]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an xpath to do that easily

```
<ListBox>
     <ListBox.ItemsSource>
          <Binding XPath="//Comment[@source='Controller']"/>
     </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

You'll still need to set the source and you might have to escape the quotes around "Controller". Here some resources to get started [How to use XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287(v=vs.110).aspx) and [XPath syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)